# For the sequence $u_n$, $u_n \to +\infty \iff \frac{1}{u_n} \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> Let $u=(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $u_n \neq 0$, $u_n \to +\infty$, for $ n \to +\infty$.
>
> Proof that $u_n \to + \infty , ( n \to +\infty)  \iff \left(( \exists n_0 , \forall n \geq n_0: u_n > 0) \wedge \left(\frac{1}{u_n} \to 0, (n \to +\infty)\right) \right)$

First I want to highlight that [Theorem: For any sequence , $b_n >0$ then $b_n \to 0$ iff limit of $\frac{1}{b_n} = \infty$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205246/theorem-for-any-sequence-b-n-0-then-b-n-to-0-iff-limit-of-frac1b-n) is closely (if not completely) analogous to this question. However, the answers given there are 'useless' for me since I'd much rather have someone to verify/falsify my steps.

Since the idea of this theorem is very simple and intuitive, I thought that the proof might as well be, however when it comes to applying the rigorous definitions I begin to struggle.

**My attempt**:

"For $ \implies$"

$u_n \to +\infty$ for big $n$ means that $u_n$ does not converge. In special, the sequence does not converge to $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

> **Definition** (Convergence): Let $u=(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The sequence is convergent and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is its limit if and only if $\forall \epsilon >, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N},(n \geq n_0 \rightarrow |u_n-a|< \epsilon)$

I wanted to use this definition because it's easy to negate, the negation would be: \begin{align}\exists \epsilon >0, \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N},(n \geq n_0 \wedge |u_n-a| \geq \epsilon) \tag{NOT converge} \end{align}
My next step was to play a bit with this expression, especially with the distance, I obtained that: \begin{align}|u_n-a| \geq \epsilon \implies |u_n| \leq \frac{1}{a+\epsilon} \iff |u_n-0|\leq \frac{1}{a+\epsilon} \end{align} with the same quantors as in the negation. Here I could tell that if I choose $\epsilon$ to be very large, then the sequence converges to zero, as desired. However it looks edgy and incomplete to me, would I have to choose for an $\epsilon_1$ and define it such that $|u_n-0| < \epsilon$ turns out?

For "$\Longleftarrow$"

The sequence $1/u_n$ converges to zero for big $n$ \begin{align} \left| \frac{1}{u_n}-0\right|< \epsilon \implies |u_n| < \frac{1}{\epsilon} \end{align}
If $\epsilon$ is small, then the sequence gets very big. I do not see how I could formulate this well in an analytic statement to conclude that $u_n$ must diverge now.

*Idea (but not worked on yet): Maybe use the contrapositive?*

Comment: For $\implies$, let me note that your negation of the convergence statement will not be strong enough for a proof. This is because there are sequences, like $(-1)^n$ that do not converge but at the same time, do not blow up to infinity.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't know what other informations I could drain out of the statement that $u_n \to +\infty, \ n \to +\infty$. So far I don't have many tools to work with at all which is quite the handicap when it comes to verifying such things.

Comment: Use the very definition of $u_n\to+\infty$, that is $\forall M\exists n_0\forall n>n_0\colon u_n>M$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I haven't seen that definition yet, I will gladly look into it, is $M$ considered to be a set or a natural number? it would make sense to me if: $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq n_0: u_n > M$. I found it, thanks a lot, I will try my luck with this definition.